# Kernel based conditional increments of many stochastic processes

Tags: performance, statistics, matlab

I have written this function is part of a research project that involves analyzing time-series data from stochastic processes. We have a small number (from 1 to 3) of independent observations of a scalar time-series. The observations have different lengths, and each contain about \$10^4-10^5\$ data points. The function below `nKBR_moments.m` takes a cell array of the observations as input, along with other settings, and outputs statistical quantities known as "moments of conditional increments". These are the variables `M1` and `M2`. For more detail of the theory, [this research paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physleta.2009.07.073) outlines a similar method.

For the research purposes the function will eventually be evaluated tens of thousands of times, on a desktop computer. One evaluation of this function takes about 3 seconds with the test script I have provided below. Thoughts on optimising code performance, memory usage or scalability are appreciated.

MATLAB function:

```matlab
function [Xcentre,M1,M2] = nKBR_moments(X,tau_in,Npoints,xLims,h)
%Kernel based moments, n-data
%
%   Notes:
%   Calculates kernel based moments for a given stochastic time-series.
%   Uses Epanechnikov kernel with built in computational advantages. Uses
%   Nadaraya-Watson estimator. Calculates moments from n sources of data.
%   
%
%   Inputs:
%   - "X"                       Observed variables, cell array of data
%   - "tau_in"                  Time-shift indexes
%   - "Npoints"                 Number of evaluation points
%   - "xLims"                   Limits in upper and lower evaluation points
%   - "h"                       Bandwidth
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% Processing
dX = (xLims(2)-xLims(1))/(Npoints-1); % Bins increment
Xcentre = xLims(1):dX:xLims(2); % Grid
heff = h*sqrt(5); % Effective bandwidth, for setting up bins
eta = floor(heff/dX+0.5); % Bandwidth for bins optimizing

% Epanechnikov kernel
K= @(u) 0*(u.^2>1)+3/4*(1-u.^2).*(u.^2<=1);
Ks = @(u) K(u/sqrt(5))/sqrt(5); % Silverman's definition of the kernel (Silverman, 1986)
Kh = @(u) Ks(u/h)/h; % Changing bandwidth

% Sort all data into bins
Bextend = dX*(eta+0.5); % Extend bins
edges = xLims(1)-Bextend:dX:xLims(2)+Bextend; % Edges
ndata = numel(X); % Number of data-sets
Xloc = cell(1,ndata); % Preallocate histogram location data
nXdata = cellfun(@numel,X); % Number of x data
key = 1:max(nXdata); % Data key
for nd = 1:ndata
    [~,~,Xloc{nd}] = histcounts(X{nd},edges); % Sort
end
Xbinloc = eta+(1:Npoints); % Bin locations
BinBeg = Xbinloc-eta; % Bin beginnings
BinEnd = Xbinloc+eta; % Bin beginnings

% Preallocate
Ntau = numel(tau_in); % Number of time-steps
[M1,M2] = deal(zeros(Ntau,Npoints)); % Moments
[iX,iXkey,XU,Khj,yinc,Khjt] = deal(cell(1,ndata)); % Preallocate increment data

% Pre calculate increments
inc = cell(Ntau,ndata);
for nd = 1:ndata
    poss_tau_ind = 1:nXdata(nd); % Possible time-shifts
    for tt = 1:Ntau
        tau_c = tau_in(tt); % Chosen shift
        tau_ind = poss_tau_ind(1+tau_c:end); % Chosen indices
        inc{tt,nd} = X{nd}(tau_ind) - X{nd}(tau_ind - tau_c);
    end
end

% Loop over evaluation points
for ii = 1:Npoints

    % Start and end bins
    kBinBeg = BinBeg(ii);
    kBinEnd = BinEnd(ii);

    % Data and weights
    for nd = 1:ndata
        iX{nd} = and(kBinBeg<=Xloc{nd},Xloc{nd}<=kBinEnd); % Data in bins
        iXkey{nd} = key(iX{nd}); % Data key
        XU{nd} = X{nd}(iX{nd}); % Unshifted data
        Khj{nd} = Kh(Xcentre(ii)-XU{nd}); % Weights
    end

    % For each shift
    for tt = 1:Ntau
        tau_c = tau_in(tt); % Chosen shift

        % Get data
        for nd = 1:ndata            
            XUin = iXkey{nd}; % Unshifted data indices
            XUin(XUin>nXdata(nd)-tau_c) = []; % Clip overflow
            yinc{nd} = inc{tt,nd}(XUin); % Increments
            Khjt{nd} = Khj{nd}(1:numel(yinc{nd})); % Clipped weight vector
        end

        % Concatenate data
        ytt = [yinc{:}];
        Khjtt = [Khjt{:}];

        % Increments and moments
        sumKhjtt = sum(Khjtt);
        M1(tt,ii) = sum(Khjtt.*ytt)/sumKhjtt;

        y2 = (ytt - M1(tt,ii)).^2; % Squared (with correction)
        M2(tt,ii) = sum(Khjtt.*y2)/sumKhjtt;
    end
end
end
```

MATLAB test script (no feedback for this required):

```matlab
%% nKBR_testing
clearvars,close all

%% Parameters

% Simulation settings
n_sims = 10; % Number of simulations
dt = 0.001; % Time-step
tend1 = 40; % Time-end, process 1
tend2 = 36; % Time-end, process 2
x0 = 0; % Start position
eta = 0; % Mean
D = 1; % Noise amplitude
gamma = 1; % Drift slope

% Analysis settings
tau_in = 1:60; % Time-shift indexes
Npoints = 50; % Number of evaluation points
xLims = [-1,1]; % Limits of evaluation
h = 0.5; % Kernel bandwidth

%% Simulating
t1 = 0:dt:tend1;
t2 = 0:dt:tend2;

% Realize an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process
rng('default')
ex1 = exp(-gamma*t1);
ex2 = exp(-gamma*t2);
x1 = x0*ex1 + eta*(1-ex1) + sqrt(D)*ex1.*cumsum(exp(gamma*t1).*[0,sqrt(2*dt)*randn(1,numel(t1)-1)]);
x2 = x0*ex2 + eta*(1-ex2) + sqrt(D)*ex2.*cumsum(exp(gamma*t2).*[0,sqrt(2*dt)*randn(1,numel(t2)-1)]);

%% Calculating and timing moments

tic
for ns = 1:n_sims
    [~,M1,M2] = nKBR_moments({x1,x2},tau_in,Npoints,xLims,h);
end
nKBR_moments_time = toc;
nKBR_average_time = nKBR_moments_time/n_sims

%% Plotting

figure
hold on,box on
plot(t1,x1)
plot(t2,x2)
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('Amplitude')
title('Two Ornstein-Uhlenbeck processes')

figure
subplot(1,2,1)
box on
plot(dt*tau_in,M1,'k')
xlabel('Time-shift, \tau')
title('M^{(1)}')
subplot(1,2,2)
box on
plot(dt*tau_in,M2,'k')
xlabel('Time-shift, \tau')
title('M^{(2)}')
```

The test script will create two figures similar to the ones below.

[image: Time-series data of two OU processes]

[image: Calculated moments of the processes]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is a bit confusing due to the large number of really short variable names, though those might match the equations in the paper you linked, I haven't looked. I would use longer, more descriptive variable names (those will also allow you to reduce the number of comments, which can only get out of synch when changing the code). Other than that, I think it's straight-forward and easy to follow.

In regards to performance, I don't immediately see any huge gains to be had. It might be possible to vectorize some operations, but the opportunities are not immediate obvious. The number 1 thing you can do to find out how to improve your speed is to profile your code. MATLAB has a built-in profiler, see [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html).

Here are a few things that can be simplified:

---

```matlab
    for nd = 1:ndata
        iX{nd} = and(kBinBeg<=Xloc{nd},Xloc{nd}<=kBinEnd); % Data in bins
        iXkey{nd} = key(iX{nd}); % Data key
        XU{nd} = X{nd}(iX{nd}); % Unshifted data
        Khj{nd} = Kh(Xcentre(ii)-XU{nd}); % Weights
    end
```

In this piece, `iX{nd}` is never used outside the loop. Neither is `XU{nd}`. Let's get rid of these (less indexing and less data storage both lead to faster code):

```matlab
    for nd = 1:ndata
        iX = and(kBinBeg <= Xloc{nd}, Xloc{nd} <= kBinEnd); % Data in bins
        iXkey{nd} = key(iX);          % Data key
        XU = X{nd}(iX);               % Unshifted data
        Khj{nd} = Kh(Xcentre(ii)-XU); % Weights
    end
```

Because `key = 1:max(nXdata)`, `key(iX)` is the same as `find(iX)`, it is likely that the latter is faster. Now you have:

```matlab
    for nd = 1:ndata
        iXkey{nd} = find((kBinBeg <= Xloc{nd}) & (Xloc{nd} <= kBinEnd));
        Khj{nd} = Kh(Xcentre(ii) - X{nd}(iXkey{nd}));
    end
```

---

This phrase:

```matlab
XUin(XUin>nXdata(nd)-tau_c) = [];
```

can also be written as:

```matlab
XUin = XUin(XUin <= nXdata(nd)-tau_c);
```

This happens inside the innermost loop, and is thus one of the lines most often executed. It is worthwhile trying both options to see which one is faster.

---

This bit is quite expensive, because it copies the data:

```matlab
        ytt = [yinc{:}];
        Khjtt = [Khjt{:}];

        % Increments and moments
        sumKhjtt = sum(Khjtt);
        M1(tt,ii) = sum(Khjtt.*ytt)/sumKhjtt;
```

It is worth while here also to see if a loop is faster than the concatenation:

```matlab
        sumKhjtt = 0;
        sumKhjtt_ytt = 0;
        for nd = 1:ndata
           sumKhjtt = sumKhjtt + sum(Khjt{nd});
           sumKhjtt_ytt = sumKhjtt_ytt + sum(Khjt{nd}.*yinc{nd});
        end
        M1(tt,ii) = sumKhjtt_ytt / sumKhjtt;
```

(and the same for M2). This loop can be included into the previous one to avoid two more cell arrays: `yinc` and `Khjt`:

```matlab
        sumKhjtt = 0;
        sumKhjtt_ytt = 0;
        for nd = 1:ndata
            XUin = iXkey{nd};
            XUin(XUin > nXdata(nd)-tau_c) = [];
            yinc = inc{tt,nd}(XUin);
            Khjt = Khj{nd}(1:numel(yinc{nd}));
            sumKhjtt = sumKhjtt + sum(Khjt{nd});
            sumKhjtt_ytt = sumKhjtt_ytt + sum(Khjt{nd}.*yinc{nd});
        end
        M1(tt,ii) = sumKhjtt_ytt / sumKhjtt;
```

You'll have to rewrite the equation for `M2` to be able to merge the summation it into that loop. This is fairly simple, it's analogous to [the naive algorithm for computing the variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Na%C3%AFve_algorithm). That algorithm is not stable, it depends on your data whether the results are good or not. If it is not, use [Welford's online algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Welford's_online_algorithm) instead. There you can compute the second order central moment of the first batch, then add to the accumulators for subsequent batches.